# Google Sheets Formula - Detecting (non)matching data in rows between two columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image]

I am trying to compare matching numbers in column AD against eachother, to check if their corresponding numbers in AF match as well. If they do not, I would like an indicator (!!!) in AG to show next to the inconsistent data points, for future use.

If **ADx**=**ADy**, but **AFx**<>**AFy**, output "!!!" to **AGx** and **AGy**.

For example, in the image:

**AD14**=**AD15**=**AD18**. But **AF14**, **AF15**, **AF18** are not all equal. So **AG14**, **AG15**, **AG18** = "!!!"

**AD21**=**AD25**=**AD27**. But **AF21**, **AF25**, **AF27** are not all equal.  So **AG21**, **AG25**, **AG27** = "!!!"

I had made a solution before but after some revamping I forgot it, and I wasn't able to replicate it, and it was hardly an elegant solution in the first place. So hopefully someone who knows what they're doing can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(countunique(ifna(filter(F:F,D:D=Σ)))>1,"❗",))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly for what I need, and is a lot more efficient than what I had before. Hopefully I'll figure out how to recreate it myself in the future!